# Is pointwise convergence permutation-invariant?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I am interested in convergence between countable sequences of real numbers. (Perhaps the definitions to follow are nonstandard. Sorry!)

Say that the sequence $\langle \langle x^1_1,x^1_2,x^1_3,...\rangle, \langle x^2_1,x^2_2,x^2_3,...\rangle, ...\rangle$ *pointwise converges* to $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,...\rangle$ iff the sequence $\langle x^1_i, x^2_i, x^3_i,...\rangle$ converges to $x_i$ for all $i$. All $x^j_i$ are real numbers, so the notion of convergence for each "coordinate" is the standard one for real numbers. By a *permutation* of a set I mean a one-one function from that set to itself.

Given these definitions, is the following statement true?

If $f$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$, and the sequence $\langle \langle x^1_1,x^1_2,x^1_3,...\rangle, \langle x^2_1,x^2_2,x^2_3,...\rangle, ...\rangle$ pointwise converges to $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,...\rangle$, then also the sequence $\langle \langle x^1_{f(1)},x^1_{f(2)},x^1_{f(3)},...\rangle, \langle x^2_{f(1)},x^2_{f(2)},x^2_{f(3)},...\rangle, ...\rangle$ pointwise converges to $\langle x_{f(1)},x_{f(2)},x_{f(3)},...\rangle$.

What if we make $f$ a *finite permutation* of $\mathbb{N}$ in the sense that $f$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ and $f(i)\neq i$ for finitely many $i$ at most?

Any references would be great, too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conjectures are certainly true:  if $\langle x^1_i, x^2_i, x^3_i,...\rangle$ converges to $x_i$ for every $i$, then $\langle x^1_{f(j)}, x^2_{f(j)}, x^3_{f(j)},...\rangle$ converges to $x_{f(j)}$, because every $f(j)$  equals $i$ for some $i$.

Since it holds for all permutations, it necessarily holds for all finite permutations.

The interesting example to consider is the one where $$x_i^j = 
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{when $i\ne j$}\\
10^{10^i}, &\text{when $i= j$}
\end{cases}
$$
Under your definition, the sequences are converging pointwise to ${\bf 0} =\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$, while under any reasonable definition of “distance”, each one is much “farther away” from $\bf 0$ than the one before.  This shows that pointwise convergence doesn't completely capture our intuitions about covergence in this space.